# Where is fusion-gmap-container?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I’ve been given a beautiful WordPress website to maintain.  We use the Avada theme.

We have a contact page, which has a large Google map, with the location of our business.  A little while ago, I added a picture of our facility, directly beneath the map.

I showed the updated page to my boss, who felt the map and the picture were both too large.  He wanted the map to be on the right third of the page and the left 2/3rds to be the picture of the facility.  I thought this would be an easy change; and that I could just use fusion builder to make these changes.

However, when I clicked to edit the contact page and examined it closer, I could not find the Google map on the page in Fusion Builder.  So I looked using the default editor, in Text and Visual; but I couldn't find it.  (Before this job, I came from a background where I did all the HTML by hand.  It was more difficult; but at least I knew where things were.)

I opened the page in Chrome and inspected the element.  This is what I see for the div where the map is:  `<div id="fusion-gmap-container">`

I had the thought that maybe `fusion-gmap-container` is a Widget.  But I can’t find it there.  This seems like it should be intuitive and easy but I’m really stumped.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried contacting the theme developer? You might get a faster response. I never used this theme, but my guess is that the map script is baked into the template, using parameters saved in the admin. If you open your themes folder, you should be able to locate the template using the map.

Comment: Thanks for that, gdaniel.  I didn't think to look there.

Answer (score 0):

In the main menu on the left, I went to Avada->Theme Options.

On that page there was an option for Contact Form (that is used in the Contact page).

Under Contact Form there is a "Google Map" option.